# Site won’t render on mobile properly

Tags: rendering, domain-masking, mobirise

So the site url points to another masked domain on my GD hosting package. My business partner owns the domain but has no hosting. So forwarded his domain to one I created and masked mine. The site looks fine on my hosting and domain. Here http://heritage-racing.co.uk. But when his domain points to it, it doesn’t render properly. Almost like desktop on mobile. Here http://heritageracingcars.com. Site was built using mobirise. Can anyone help. Thank you.

Tried to forward a domain name to another domain.